# How can I add a role to a GCP Service Account

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform

Using the GPC .NET C# API, I am able to successfully create a Service Account for my GCP Project.  How can I add Roles to my new Service Account?  Presumably this is done through SetIamPolicy however the [examples](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#whats_next) only show setting the Roles for Projects.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to grant new Roles to your GCP Service Account(s) you can do it via the Console by following these steps:

1. Go to your [IAM Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam)  in your GCP Project. Here you will find all your accounts: users and service accounts.
2. Search for the Service Account you want to modify. At the very right of that line you will see a [Pencil Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glyb7.png), click on it. A new panel will show up.
3. Click on [ADD ANOTHER ROLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rnZ6.png) and select the roles you want to grant to that account. You can add more than one, but you will need to click `ADD ANOTHER ROLE` every time.
4. Click on Save and your Service Account will be ready.

It can take up to 2 minutes to be fully reflected but in the best case, the changes are done immediately.

Another option is to use the command [gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding) which allows you to do these changes via the Cloud SDK. A quick example:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding example-project-id-1 \
--member='user:test-user@gmail.com' \
--role='roles/editor'
```

That command will grant the `Editor Role` to the account `test-uster@gmail.com`. You would need to modify that command to set the Service Account and the Roles you want to grant.

This might require more steps on your end as you need to make sure that the syntax for the service account and Roles. The fastest way to use Cloud SDK is via a [Cloud Shell session](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I needed to set the permissions for a Service Account, not a User.  So the correct CLI would be:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding \
 test-proj1@example.domain.com \
 --member='serviceAccount:test-proj1@example.domain.com' \
 --role='roles/editor'
```

And this led me to the solution for my .NET project -- so thanks!  In the binding API, the member must be prefixed with "serviceAccount:", just like the CLI.  So, the full member name for the Binding used in SetPolicy would be:

```
  var member = "serviceAccount:" + "test-proj1@example.domain.com";
```

See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/iam/api/QuickStartTest/QuickStartTest.cs) for a more complete example.